# How to iterate through object, displaying only results mutual to all of its elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, foreach, iteration

I am making simple app, written on Angular7, that gets input of products (ex. "apple orange strawberry") and displays recipes that have all of the products as an ingredient. Everything needed such as recipes, ingredients and so on is saved in JSON file. It works only when I have one product as an input. The thing is that I want to iterate through all of the ingredients in the input and display the recipes, which ingredients have all of the products.

This is what an object of JSON file looks like:

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "some name",
      "ingredients": "some ingredients",
      "recipe": "some recipe"
    }
```

This is how I get the input as an object and then split it so I can get each ingredient:

```
 this.pattern = this.searchForm.value;
 this.patternObj = this.pattern.name.split(" ");
```

This is how I filter and collect the elements that have the certain ingredient:

```
this.result = res.filter(v => v.ingredients.indexOf(this.patternObj) > -1);
```

I tried to foreach the patternObj, but in this case it displays only the recipes for the last product of the object.

Comment: You should use an array for storing ingredients, makes things much simpler

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function `some` instead to check for at least one element, and the function `includes` to check if one element exists in the target array.

```
this.result = res.filter(v => v.ingredients.some(ing => this.patternObj.includes(ing)));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error, because v.ingredients has no `some` method

Comment: @Ana that’s because your ingredients object isn’t an array but a string

Comment: @Ana What is this `v.ingredients`? Can you post the content?

Comment: I used v.ingredients as a parameter to filter all the objects that have the input as value of the ingredients key 

`this.result = res.filter(v => v.ingredients.indexOf(this.patternObj) > -1); `

Ingredients is the property of the object, that holds all ingredients for each recipe.